# filter rows from Postgres table based on specific conditions without missing relevant rows

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I have table with following columns in postgres.

```
col1    col2             col3
1       Other            a
2       Drug             b    
1       Procedure        c
3       Combination Drug d
4       Biological       e
3       Behavioral       f
3       Drug             g
5       Drug             g
6       Procedure        h
```

I would like to filter rows based on following filters.

```
select col1, col2, col3
from tbl
where col2 in ('Other', 'Drug', 'Combination Drug', 'Biological')
```

But this query will exclude below rows

```
1       Procedure        c
3       Behavioral       f
```

The Desired output is:

```
col1    col2             col3
1       Other            a
1       Procedure        c
2       Drug             b    
3       Combination Drug d
3       Behavioral       f
3       Drug             g
4       Biological       e
5       Drug             g
```

How can I achieve the above output without missing the mentioned rows.

Any suggestion here will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: edited the post. so row with id = 6 should be excluded from the desired table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the rows where there is as `col1` containing any of the values of `col2` in the list:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from tbl
where col1 in (
  select col1 from tbl 
  where col2 in ('Other', 'Drug', 'Combination Drug', 'Biological')
)
order by col1;
```

Or with `EXISTS`:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from tbl t
where exists (
  select 1 from tbl 
  where col1 = t.col1 
  and col2 in ('Other', 'Drug', 'Combination Drug', 'Biological')
)
order by col1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMSoYMfDGrSs4iGAirkHij/1).